# How do I get Python2.x `map` functionality in Python3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

The signature for `map` is

```
map(function, iterable[, iterables[, ...]])
```

In Python 2.x if `function` is `None` identity is assumed, and short iterables are padded with 'None' to the length of the longest iterable.

In Python 3.x if `function` is `None` you eventually get an exception:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

and all iterables are trimmed to the length of the shortest one.

That's a couple of pretty drastic changes.  How do I get 2.x semantics back?

Oh, and it now returns an iterator instead of a list, but I'm okay with that change. ;)

---

This is useful for cases where you don't know ahead of time which function, if any, will be applied -- just because you aren't actually transforming the iterable doesn't mean you don't want its contents.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with of the function is "None" or not. You do not "Eventually" get the error, you get it the first time. You simply can't pass in None any more. The problem is that map() in Python 3 will stop at the shortest iterable. I'm not sure why this change was done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must roll your own -- but it's easy:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, starmap

def map2x(func, *iterables):
    if len(iterables) == 1:
        zipped = list(iterables[0])
    else:
        zipped = zip_longest(*iterables)
    if func is None:
        return zipped
    return starmap(func, zipped)
```

A simple example:

```
a=['a1']
b=['b1','b2','b3']
c=['c1','c2']

print(list(map2x(None, a, b, c)))
```

which gives us:

```
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), (None, 'b2', 'c2'), (None, 'b3', None)]
```

If you have only one iterable, like:

```
map(None, 'hello world')
```

Then simply replace that with:

```
list('hello world')
```

Update:

My original answer here didn't work if you called `map()` with `None` as function and only one iterable. That's because nobody does that, since then you can just as well just use `list(iterable)`. But I added the handling of that case anyway, by popular request. :-)

Comment: I don't agree with the not importing inside functions (except for `from ... import *` -- that's definitely not good, as well as not allowed in Python 3.x), but I like your other improvements.  Thanks!

Comment: @EthanFurman: It should really only be done to avoid circular imports, or if you have misbehaving modules that you only want to import if you really need them. Otherwise it slows down and clutters the code.

Comment: Funny how the source code of `future` points to this as being wrong and says it is [difficult to get the original map right](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/past/builtins/noniterators.py#L55). Can you edit this answer to tell people to use that library instead of rolling your own?

Comment: No, because the future library should be avoided, it's just a lot of trouble. I can certainly update the example, once I understand their issue.

Comment: Ah, the case of having only one iterable and None as a function wasn't supported, which is because that's a silly example, since you can do the same thing by just calling `list()`. So I added that feature.