# zip in or out a comprehension of python

Tags: python, zip, list-comprehension

```
list(zip(['A','B','C'], [x for x in range(1,4)]))
```

I want to rewrite above to let that zip inside the comprehension. Below is a try:

```
[list(zip(['A','B','C'], x) for x in range(1,4))]
```

or 
   `[zip(['A','B','C'], x) for x in range(1,4)]`

It doesn't work and comes a **TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration**

May i know where went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[x for x in range(1,4)]` is nothing more than `list(range(1, 4))`, so use:

```
list(zip(['A', 'B', 'C'], range(1, 4)))
```

and be done with it.

If you *have* to use a list comprehension, replace the `list()` call:

```
[(x, y) for x, y in zip(['A', 'B', 'C'], range(1, 4))]
```

but that is just as redundant as the inner list comprehension.

What you are trying to do is pass individual elements to the `zip()` function, which only takes sequences.

Comment: Redundant but clear for me though. You know I'm still learning. If type begin with [(x,y) for ...] I would know what type and how many elements it's going to come out before reading all the code down. So for me list(zip(['A', 'B', 'C'], range(1, 4))) is more lengthy than comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You could actually use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)'s ability to zip its arguments passed:

```
>>> map(None, ['A','B','C'], range(1,4)) # For python 2.x only
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
```

The error with your code is that it's passing a number to the second argument of zip, instead of an iterator.

Comment: Thanks. I use 3.3.2 and put the code in will appear 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: @afternoon Huh, never knew that happened. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072755/how-do-i-get-python2-x-map-functionality-in-python3-x)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
>>> some_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> enumerate(some_list)
```

Although this would give you the pairs in reverse order, starting from zero and as an Iterable not a list `(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C')` (an Interable is often more efficient though). If you wanted specifically to start from 1, you can pass in the start value to enumerate as the 2nd argument and you could also convert to a list afterwards:

```
>>> list(enumerate(some_list, 1))
[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')]
```

This still gives the pairs in reverse order to the question though.

This technique is common when you want the index and element from a list:

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate('ABC'):
...     print i, c
...
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

Comment: Thanks the enumerate(___, 1)) really works. And I got a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when trying your third code. It red light the "i". May I know what's the i and c stand for?