# Python list rearranging

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to port a section of code from `Python2` to `Python3`, one function in this code returns a list of tuples representing a table, but as these values are fetched from several `tkinter` `listboxes` this happens in two steps:

1. Fetch the complete column from each listbox in turn
2. Invert the list from a tuple per column to tuple per row

in `Python2` the line that does this is:

```
apply(map, [None] + result)
```

and i haven't got a clue how this actually works or how to port it, i have had a look through the docs and everything i can see on how to port to `Python3` for apply or map doesn't actually achieve what i want it to.

I am using `Python 3.3`, a flexible answer would be preferred as the number of columns is not fixed.

as an example:

```
[("c1r1","c1r2","c1r3"),("c2r1","c2r2","c2r3"),("c3r1","c3r2","c3r3")]
```

needs to go to:

```
[("c1r1","c2r1","c3r1"),("c1r2","c2r2","c3r2"),("c1r3","c2r3","c3r3")]
```

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be very helpful here. Have you tried anything or do you just want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: [`apply()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) has been deprecated, don't use it in Python 2 either.

Comment: i don't really want to use it, i've removed it everywhere else in the code, but i can't work out how to remove it on this line

Comment: I don't think your code snippet is valid -- it will produce a TypeError. `apply(map, sequence)` is equivalent to `map(sequence)`, but map also needs a function. ie. `map(function, sequence)`.

Comment: You're looking for `zip(*yourlist)` or `list(zip(*yourlist))` in Python 3.

Comment: Unless the `map` function was overridden somewhere, this code is broken. It would call `map(None, *result)` and `None` is not a valid function so `map()` couldn't call that.

Comment: this is why i cant work out how it's working, i have the entire source, of less than 200 lines, its a single file with only one import, which is import tkinter as tk, yet somehow this works without errors

Comment: @AshwiniChaudHary can you put your comment as an answer please, the second function: `list(zip(*yourlist))` does exactly what i needed. Thanks

Comment: Related: [How do I get Python2.x `map` functionality in Python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072755/how-do-i-get-python2-x-map-functionality-in-python3-x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> result = [("c1r1","c1r2","c1r3"),("c2r1","c2r2","c2r3"),("c3r1","c3r2","c3r3")]
>>> apply(map, [None] + result)
[('c1r1', 'c2r1', 'c3r1'), ('c1r2', 'c2r2', 'c3r2'), ('c1r3', 'c2r3', 'c3r3')]
```

Calls `map` with first parameter `None` and then the 3 tuples as the remaining parameters. Equivalent to:

```
>>> map(None, *result)
[('c1r1', 'c2r1', 'c3r1'), ('c1r2', 'c2r2', 'c3r2'), ('c1r3', 'c2r3', 'c3r3')]
```

However for this operation you should use `zip(*result)` which is cross compatible

```
>>> zip(*result)
[('c1r1', 'c2r1', 'c3r1'), ('c1r2', 'c2r2', 'c3r2'), ('c1r3', 'c2r3', 'c3r3')]
```

On Python 3 you may want to use `list(zip(*result))` if you need a list.

Comment: Might add a note about how `map` in Python 2 took `None` as the identity function, so that `map(None, *lists)` was in fact equivalent to `zip(*lists)` in Python 2, but `map` in Python 3 seems not to accept `None` as function parameter anymore.